# How Do I Load My Action Earlier Enough?

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, actions

With add_action, I want to intercept as early as I can in my plugin and send a 304 Not Modified header per some rules. **Does anyone know what the order is of events?** When I view [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request), it seems to hint that the best place for this would be plugins_loaded, and that it comes before the init event. Is that correct? The page in that link doesn't describe what the event order is, but seems to imply it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The page you referenced does have the correct order of events listed there. If you want to see which events were fired for a particular request you can install [debug-bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/) and [debug-bar-action-hooks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar-action-hooks/).

If you are wanting to send a header either `plugins_loaded` or `init` will work. But it is recommended to use the `send_headers` action that is fired just after the request is parsed, also if your rules depend on data in `WP_Query` you will need to use `send_headers`.

Comment: Hikari Hooks Troubleshooting is another excellent plugin for this.

Comment: From what I can tell from this debug-bar plugin, the `plugins_loaded` event is the best place to run what I was trying to do -- it runs before `init`.